# How to measure height of inline equations

Tags: equations, inline, height, measure

How to measure the height of the below inline equation?

Here the equation contains the fraction so its height should be beyond the normal text height so I want to measure the exact height of the inline equation.

The height of this inline equation `${\text{IR}}u_{i,t} \le \frac{{q_{i,t} - q_{i,t - 1} + M_{i} + m_{i} - 0.5ru_{i} }}{{M_{i} + m_{i} + 0.5ru_{i} }}$` is ??

Comment: Unrelated, please don't use `\text` to mark something upright. It does not do what you think it does. Here use `\mathrm`

Answer (score 6):

> Here the equation contains the fraction so its height should be beyond the normal text height so I want to measure the exact height of the inline equation.

While it's true that the height -- and depth too, by the way -- of an inline equation increases if it contains a `\frac` expression, it is *not true* that this increase automatically requires you (or LaTeX...) to do anything special. As the upper third of the following screenshot demonstrates, the presence of your inline equation does not necessitate an increase in line spacing.

The screenshot hopefully also demonstrates that the fact that it's not absolutely necessary to increase line spacing does not imply that it's actually a good idea to feature a longish `\frac` expression inside a paragraph. The middle third of the screenshot shows the same inline equation, but with inline-fraction notation (aka "slash notation") instead of `\frac` notation. I hope you will agree that the paragraph with the inline-fraction equation is far more readable.

A final comment: If you really need to show the equation with `\frac` notation, please do so using a display-math environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
$\mathrm{IR}u_{i,t} \le \frac{{q_{i,t} - q_{i,t - 1} + M_{i} + m_{i} - 0.5ru_{i} }}{{M_{i} + m_{i} + 0.5ru_{i} }}$
\lipsum[1][4-6]

\bigskip
\lipsum[1][1-3]
$\mathrm{IR}u_{i,t} \le (q_{i,t} - q_{i,t - 1} + M_{i} + m_{i} - 0.5ru_{i})/(M_{i} + m_{i} + 0.5ru_{i})$
\lipsum[1][4-6]

\bigskip
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\[
\mathrm{IR}u_{i,t} \le \frac{q_{i,t} - q_{i,t - 1} + M_{i} + m_{i} - 0.5ru_{i} }{M_{i} + m_{i} + 0.5ru_{i} }
\]
\lipsum[1][4-6]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set the formula to box0 and measure its `\ht0` and `\dp0`. For example:

```
\newdimen\htmath
\newdimen\dpmath

\def\measure$#1${\setbox0=\hbox{$#1$}\htmath=\ht0 \dpmath=\dp0 \unhbox0 }

The height of this inline equation
\measure ${\rm IR} u_{i,t} \le { q_{i,t} - q_{i,t-1} + M_i + m_i - 0.5ru_i \over M_i + m_i + 0.5ru_i }$
is \the\htmath+\the\dpmath.

\bye
```

Answer (score 4):

The appropriate LaTeX idiom would be something like

```
\newlength{\mathmeasureheight}
\newlength{\mathmeasuredepth}
\newcommand{\measuremath}[1]{%
  \settoheight{\mathmeasureheight}{$#1$}%
  \settodepth{\mathmeasuredepth}{$#1$}%
}
```

but then you should do something with the information. So, let's say you want to take decisions according the either height or depth: if either is greater than the corresponding dimension of a strut, we'll typeset the formula in a display, otherwise inline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength{\mathmeasureheight}
\newlength{\mathmeasuredepth}
\newcommand{\mathmeasure}[1]{%
  \settoheight{\mathmeasureheight}{$#1$}%
  \settodepth{\mathmeasuredepth}{$#1$}%
  \ifdim\mathmeasureheight<\ht\strutbox
    \ifdim\mathmeasuredepth<\dp\strutbox
      $#1$%
    \else
      \[#1\]%
    \fi
  \else
    \[#1\]%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

Dummy text here dummy text here dummy text here.
The height of this inline equation 
\mathmeasure{\mathrm{IR}u_{i,t} \le 
\frac{{q_{i,t} - q_{i,t - 1} + M_{i} + m_{i} - 0.5ru_{i} }}{{M_{i} + m_{i} + 0.5ru_{i} }}}
doesn't fit in the line.
Dummy text here dummy text here dummy text here.
Dummy text here dummy text here dummy text here.

Dummy text here dummy text here dummy text here.
The height of this inline equation 
\mathmeasure{\frac{a}{b}}
fits in the line.
Dummy text here dummy text here dummy text here.
Dummy text here dummy text here dummy text here.

\end{document}
```

[image]